# Translation-golf XXV - I'd rather be shiny

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> This edition of the game has ended! The winner is @walen!

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This edition's proposed text is the beginning of the song *Shiny* from the Disney movie *Moana* (known in Europe as *Vaiana* because [pr0n](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3521164/trivia?item=tr3193043)<sub>[SFW]</sub>).

You can watch and listen the whole song clip here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93lrosBEW-Q

> Well, Tamatoa hasn't always been this glam
>   I was a drab little crab once
>   Now I know I can be happy as a clam
>   Because I'm beautiful, baby
>
> Did your granny say listen to your heart
>   Be who you are on the inside
>   I need three words to tear her argument apart
>   Your granny lied!
>   I'd rather be...
>
> Shiny
>   Like a treasure from a sunken pirate wreck
>   Scrub the deck and make it look...
>
> Shiny
>   I will sparkle like a wealthy woman's neck
>   Just a sec!
>
> <sub>(333 characters)</sub>

I will add here the Spanish (from Spain) version of the song. It is more an adaptation than a literal translation, but here it goes:

> Hace tiempo no tenía este glamour
>  Fui un cangrejito muy soso
>  Pero ahora estoy feliz y en plenitud
>  Porque soy muy bello nena
>
>  Tu corazón tu abuela te hizo escuchar
>  Sé como eres por dentro
>  Ese argumento yo lo voy a desmontar
>  ¡Ella mintió!
>  Mejor ser...
>
>  ¡Brillante!
>  Cual tesoro de un navío que se hundió
>  La cubierta tengo...
>
>  ¡Brillante!
>  Igualito que un collar de un millón
>  ¡Un segundo!
>
>  <sub>(299 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

As this is a song text, the **bonus for rhymes** applies. So if you maintain the rhymes in the verses, you get a 10% discount in your character count. **The rhymes to be maintained are the ones from the following verses: *glam* with *clam*, *heart* with *apart*, and *wreck* with *neck*.** The rest of the verses are rhyme-free. Only proper rhymes will be accepted, so no assonant rhymes apply for the bonus this time.

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### <s>263 259</s> 237 (<s>237 234</s> 214 con bonus)

> Tamatoa siempre mono no fue
>   Era un gris cangrejito
>   Feliz cual almeja puedo ser, ya sé
>   Pues soy lindo, nena
>
> Dijo tu yaya: oye tu corazón
>   Sé tu ser
>   1 voz para partir su razón
>   ¡Mintió!
>   Mejor...
>
> Lucir
>   Cual tesoro de naufragio pirata
>   Friega el piso y hazlo...
>
> Lucir
>   Fulgiré cual cuello de la flor y nata
>   Espera!

Answer (score 2):

#### <s>324 296 236</s> 219 caracteres con bonus de rima

> Ayer no tenia brío
> era un lacio cangrejín
> hoy puedo ser feliz cual crío
> porque soy bello, nena
>
> Tu yaya dijo haz caso al corazón
> sé tu mismo
> Pero hago trizas su razón
> !Miente!
> prefiero...
>
> Brillar
> cual tesoro hundido bucanero
> lava la cubierta y que
>
> Brille
> luciré cual cuello de mujer de dinero
> solo un tris

- Elimino el nombre *Tomatoa* porque habla de si mismo.
- Uso *ayer* y *hoy* en lugar de *antes* y *ahora*.
- Cambio la comparación de ser *feliz como una almeja* por *ser feliz como un crío* que no cambia el significado de la frase.
- Para decir *Be who you are on the inside* uso la expresión *sé tu mismo* que viene a ser lo mismo mismamente.
- **tris:** Porción muy pequeña de tiempo o de lugar, causa u ocasión levísima; poca cosa, casi nada.